# JQuery event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code to scroll a block with mousewheel:

```
$('.master').hover(function(){ 
    var val = -100;
    $(document).mousewheel(function(event,delta) {
        if(delta > 0) {
            val+=10;
        }
        if(delta < 0) {
            val-=10;
        }

        $("#slider02").html(val);
        $('.master .slide-text').css('margin-top', val);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

How to return default actions, mouse pointer is outer of block `.master`?
I tried putting `return false`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to prevent scrolling within some div? If so you may be able to just use overflow:hidden with css

Comment: Sorry for my English. I need, when cursor leave block .master - return scroll browser and stop scroll block .master

Comment: js fiddle example please

Comment: Have you checked the jQuery .hover() doc - http://api.jquery.com/hover/. You might be interested in the handlers and/or the .off option.

Comment: I tried mouseover/mouseout. No return default scroll function in browser